# Microsoft.Offfice.Interop.Word, Replacing matches in all document but not header/footer C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to "Find and Replace" with code in a .doc template to replace some values from my application, it is working right now but it's not replacing the header/footer, just the body of the word document (which is great), but I also need to replace the header/footer.

This is what I have in my code:

FindAndReplace Method:

```
private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, object findText, object replacewithText)
{
    object matchCase = true;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundLike = false;
    object nmacthAllForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiactitics = false;
    object matchAleftHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;

     wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike, ref nmacthAllForms,
        ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replacewithText, ref replace, ref matchKashida,
        ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAleftHamza, ref matchControl);           
}
```

And this is my method which replace a tag like `<date>` and is replaced by the desired value with the application:

```
` public void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs, string [] InformationToReplace, int DocumentToSave)
    {
        object missing = Missing.Value;

        word.Application wordApp = new word.Application();

        word.Document aDoc = null;

        if (File.Exists((string)filename))
        {             
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;

            wordApp.Visible = false;

            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            aDoc.Activate();

            if (DocumentToSave == 0)
                requirements(wordApp, InformationToReplace);
            else if (DocumentToSave == 1)
                TechnicalDesign(wordApp, InformationToReplace);


            //Update the generic Information
             this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Today_Date>", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }

 aDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

}
```

In this case if `<Today_Date` is found in the word document is replaced by the value, but is `<Today_Date` tag is in the footer, is not replaced...

any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Depending on the bigger picture of what you're trying to do here, you may be interested in looking at Word's Mail Merge feature. I wrote an application about 18 years ago (yikes) that did the same sort of seach-and-replace automation on a bunch of replacement tokens for a bunch of different input records. It performed very poorly and was really just a reinvention of the Mail Merge wheel.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check headers and footers separately, using the `Document.StoryRanges[WdStoryType]` property.

You also have to check separately for text boxes, though for those, you have to get the text box out of each paragraph using `Range.ShapeRange`, check its type, and access its `TextFrame.TextRange` (there is a WdTextFrameStory but it only works on the first text box in the document, so it's not very helpful).

```
foreach (Range range in doc.StoryRanges)
{
  if (range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesHeaderStory)
  {
    // do work on header for even pages
  }
  else if (range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory)
  {
    // do work on main content
    foreach (Paragraph para in range.Paragraphs)
    {
      foreach (Interop.Shape shape in para.Range.ShapeRange)
      {
        if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
        {
          // do work on text box range
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: What `Document.StoryRanges[wdStoryType]` does?

Comment: A document is split up into different 'stories'. You plug in the appropriate `WdStoryType` value and it will give you the `Range` you need to work with.

Comment: Do you have some examples? just to have an idea what can do.

Comment: I've added some sample code, but you haven't asked about anything in particular so I don't know what is still unclear.

Comment: Cant he just loop all StoryRanges and use their Find object? You mean TextBoxes aren't included in the stories? And why does the code assume there are no shapes in the headers and footers if so?

Comment: 1. He already has the Find part, I didn't feel the need to replicate it. 2. Yes. 3. I don't see why anyone would put a text box in the footer or header, but you could look for them there too, if you wanted.